# Split with regular expression or custom string parsing?

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I'm looking for the most efficient way, using JavaScript, to split a string into an array of sub-strings with the following condition. The string should be split at each new occurrence of an uppercase letter from A to G.

In example:

```
String 1. 'A-7C^6'
String 2. 'Db7 B#4'
String 3. 'Eh6 GoF7'
```

Becomes:

```
Array 1. {'A-7','C^6'}
Array 2. {'Db7','B#4'}
Array 3. {'Eh6','Go','F7'}
```

I'm wondering if there is a regular expression split that would accomplish this or if i will have to write a custom string parser. Any input will be greatly appreciated. Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need lookahead zero-length asssertion:

```
'A-7C^6'.split(/\s*(?=[A-G])/)
```

[Lookahead asssertion](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) `(?=[A-G])` is a type of assertions that matches a pattern but does not include the pattern in result. For example, if you just split your string `'A-7C^6'` by `/[A-G]/`, the result is `["", "-7", "^6"]`. That's because JS removes the matched string from result. But with `/\s*(?=[A-G])/` it still matches `[A-G]` but does not include it in result, so `split` does not touch those chars.

Comment: This is a nice solution, but could use more of a plain-english explanation for future readers who might not get all that at a glance. +1

Comment: @StephenP thank you, updated the answer, hope it is understandable.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oleg! I did, however, forget to mention that I'm looking to exclude any occurrence of the '\' character and also exclude anything that is encapsulated in brackets, including the brackets. Sorry that i forgot to mention this earlier and thank you for this solution

Comment: @atasca10 can you give some sample strings?

Comment: @Oleg K. sure:

String 1. 'A^7/D7'
String 2. 'G-7(B^7) A7'
Array 1. {'A^7', 'D7'}
Array 2. {'G-7', 'A7'}

Comment: @atasca10 looks like some school homework. `'G-7(B^7) A7'.replace(/\([^(]*\)|\\/g, '').split(/\s*(?=[A-G])/)`

Comment: @Oleg K. Thanks again, that works perfectly. This is for a web application for musicians that I am developing and intend to release as open source.